# How to have multiple (non-file) dependencies in a Makefile

Tags: bash, macos, makefile, sh, gnu-make

I have a Makefile of the following form:

```
upload_image_local: build_image_local ; echo "This gets printed" ; upload_image
```

with

```
build_image_local: echo "This is build_image_local"
    ./my_shell_script_1.sh $(SOME_ENV_VAR_1)

upload_image: echo "This is upload_image"
    ./my_shell_script_2.sh $(SOME_ENV_VAR_2)
```

As you can tell, when I run `make upload_image_local`, I want `build_image_local` and `upload_image` to be run. Instead I get:

```
/bin/sh: upload_image: command not found
```

I know for file dependencies we put spaces between them, but here I'm not sure how to separate the two statements properly. I also tried putting them in the next line with semicolons and a tab character (I know it matters):

```
upload_image_local:
    build_image_local ; echo "This gets printed" ; upload_image
```

In which case I get:

```
/bin/sh: build_image_local: command not found
make: *** [upload_image_local] Error 127
```

What is the correct way to run this target? Also, why do the `echo` commands get printed fine? If it matters I'm running this Makefile on a Mac and with the `sh` shell (as it says).

Comment: Please read the docs mentioned below.  As they will show, you cannot "mix and match" prerequisites like `build_image_local` and script commands like `echo ...`.  The syntax of a rule is `*target* : *prerequisites* ; *recipe*` (where you can use a newline/TAB instead of a semicolon between the prerequisites and recipe if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

I would really advise you to take a tutorial on Make.

- [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)
- [Quickstart](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_quick_guide.htm)

To achieve the desired effect, I think the following should work:

```
all: upload_image

build_image_local:
    echo "This is build_image_local"
    ./my_shell_script_1.sh  $$SOME_ENV_VAR_1

upload_image_local: build_image_local
    echo "This gets printed"

upload_image: upload_image_local
    echo "This is upload_image"
    ./my_shell_script_2.sh $$SOME_ENV_VAR_2
```

Also, I am assuming `SOME_ENV_VAR_1` and `SOME_ENV_VAR_2` are shell variables which is why I wrote them as `$$SOME_ENV_VAR_1` and `$$SOME_ENV_VAR_2`. If they are variables of your Makefile then turn them back to way they were.

Also remember that the recipe in Makefile would spawn a subshell and you need to make sure that your env vars are available to those subshells.